# CSS3 animation transform jumping at osx Chrome

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I am having an issue with Chrome (v. 67) at OSX and movement animations. I've prepared JS fiddle with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/5m173ghv/31/

If you open it at safari it is working very good. But, when you will use chrome it has little lags when moving.

I cannot describe it a bit more... You need to open it and try yourself on the big screen... Please look carefully at white box. You will see that this box has sometimes something like lags or small jumps(?)...

This is very weird. I've tried almost every answer from the internet (trust me ;) ).

I also tried:

- Change transforms at animation into position (left)
- Change animations into transitions
- adding additional parameters (backface-visibility, perspective, will-change...)
- Changing sequences of animation to have more steps (per 10%)
- Debugging on chrome dev tools (~30-40fps)
- Adding transforms like translateZ(0)

You think that this is chrome bug or maybe my fault? Do you have any solution for that?

---

Here you have code:

HTML

```
<span class="spark"></div>
```

SCSS

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

@keyframes left-to-right {
    0% {
      transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(50vw,0,0);
    }
}

.spark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 322px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
    animation: left-to-right 5s infinite linear;
    will-change: transform;
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: i suggest you look at this resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations, consider taking out excess css attributes, and also remove browser-added margins/padding using the asterisk (*) at the top of your css https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_all.asp (select all)

Comment: Hmmm... But as you see this is only white box with black BG outside. There is no such properties like margins or padding. Could you please explain it a little bit more or modify my code at jsfiddle and show me how you see it?